# How to target and change element style using global CSS or javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to change the css style of an element (background-color) using either global CSS or javascript. How do I target that specific element and then change it?

[image]

I have tried this, using global css:

```
#contactBoxSede parallax-wrapper parallax-background {
background-color: rgb(255, 0, 128);
}
```

```
<div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-12" id="contactBoxSede"><div class="vc_column-inner">
<div class="wpb_wrapper">   
<div class="fullsize parallax-bg">
<div class="parallax-wrapper parallax-background " data-stellar-background-ratio="0.6" style="">
<div style=" background-color: rgba(255,221,0, 0.9) !important;">
```

Comment: If the highlighted div in your screenshot is the one you're trying to change, you should be able to do it with `#contactBoxSede .parallax-wrapper.parallax-background div:first-of-type { background-color: rgb(255, 0, 128); }`.

Comment: It's impossible to change an element with inline style `!important` using css. You have to remove that `!important` in HTML or use javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the style of element you can use

```
document.querySelector($selector).style.color = "green"


$selector can be name of html element , class, id or any combinaton of them.
```